# Only one document in dbs - how to update it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a node js program where I only want to allow one document in a specific collection.

Mongo Schema:

```
var DefaultPollSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    milliseconds: Number
});
```

So the collection always looks like this:

```
> db.defaultpolls.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58500051a4b71d0c4d5c6ab3"), "milliseconds" : 15000, "__v" : 0 }
```

I want to create an API for updating this value, however I do not want to use the objectId in order to do the update. Since I will only have one document in this collection - is there a way to do it?

I tried using this:

```
router.put('/update', function(req, res, next) {
  var milliseconds = req.body.milliseconds;
    defaultPoll.updateMany({}, {$set: {milliseconds: milliseconds}}, function (err, interval){
      if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          res.json(interval);
        }
    })
});
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: Object function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model)) {
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    }
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  } has no method 'updateMany'
```

Is there any other way to write the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method for Mongoose updates is called [`update`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update), so the approach is fine, but it should be:

```
defaultPoll.update({}, {$set: {milliseconds: milliseconds}}, function (err, raw) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

JohnnyHK's solution will not work. [Mongoose documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-update) mentions the following:

> Passing an empty object {} as the doc will result in a no-op unless
>   the overwrite option is passed. Without the overwrite option set, the
>   update operation will be ignored and the callback executed without
>   sending the command to MongoDB so as to prevent accidently
>   overwritting documents in the collection.

So the following code should work in your case 
(*Note the { overwrite: true } as options*):

```
router.put('/update', function(req, res, next) {
  var milliseconds = req.body.milliseconds;
    defaultPoll.update({}, {$set: {milliseconds: milliseconds}}, { overwrite: true }, function (err, interval){
      if (err) {
          res.json(err);
        } else {
          res.json(interval);
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: That note in the docs is referring to the _second_ parameter to `update` (the `$set` object), not the first.